# Get data retrieved asynchronously from Firebase from Activity in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an Activity that holds 6 Fragments (NavigationDrawer Activity). In each of these Fragments, I need access to `User` data stored in Firebase. Now, in `onCreateView()` of my fragments I can call:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in: " + firebaseUser.getUid());
                valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        teylurUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(TeylurUser.class);                          
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };

                mDatabaseReference.child("users")
                        .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
                mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not load content at this time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

and get `TeylurUser` from DataSnapshot. But it seems excessive calling this code in all six Fragments. I've decided to call the code in the `onCreate()` method of containing Activity and then save fields of TeylurUser in global variables and then access them in each Fragment using accessor methods like this:

```
businessAddress = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getBusinessAddress();
```

**The problem**

Unless I wrap any code that tries to use `businessAddress` in an `if (businessAddress != null)` statement, app crashes with a `NullPointerException`

but if `onCreateView` is called a second time, `businessAddress` is not null.

I tried querying the MainActivity in the `onAttach()` method of the Fragment with no luck.

The only solution I can think of right now is to save TeylurUser in a SQLite database, and then use the database data in my Fragments, but I just need to know if my current approach is doable.

Comment: You can try using your application class and save TeylurUser there or try attaching fragments after the TeylurUser is retrieved in containing activity.

Comment: That too fails.Tried it before.It seems all access to datasnapshot data must be done in the `onDataChange()` method of `ValueEventListener`

Comment: attach your fragments to the containing activity after the Teyluruser is retrieved. since firebase listener runs asynchronously and probably thats the reason before TeylurUser is initialized your fragments throws nullpointer exception.

Comment: Or create a listener interface which notifies your fragments that TeylurUser is retrieved.

Comment: I'll try the listener interface option and post an update soon.Thanks